# Use text length of a field avlue as value for function score with decay function

Tags: elasticsearch

I`m trying to use the length of a text field as base for a elasticsearch decay function

```
"function_score": {
    "gauss": {
        "doc['slug'].value.length()": {
            "origin": 0,
            "offset": 0,         
            "decay": 0.5,
            "scale": 10
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work. `doc['slug'].value.length()` is not a valid field.

Does somebody have an idea on how to do this calculation. Goal is: The longer the string, the less the score should be.

I hacked it with this query:

```
"function_score": {
    "score_mode": "multiply",         
    "functions": [{
        "script_score": {                
            "script": "20.0 / (doc['slug'].value.length() + 0.1)" # +0.1 to avoid division through zero
        }
    }]
}
```

But I have to set a fixed max value there (20.0). A decay function would be much more beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution:

```
"function_score": {
    "score_mode": "multiply",         
    "functions": [{
        "script_score": {                
            "source" : "decayNumericLinear(params.origin, params.scale, params.offset, params.decay, doc['slug'].value.length())",
            "params": { 
                "origin": 0,
                "scale": 10,
                "decay" : 0.5,
                "offset" : 0
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

More infos in elasticsearch docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-score-query.html